# Directory.Delete close program without Extension

Tags: c#, winforms, directory.delete

I have a little problem. I did a program (WinForms C#) which copy files from disk to removable media.

This is my process in loop:

- Source file are *.exe (sfx archive)
- Unzipping *.exe with 7z.exe via ProcessInfo (Something else didnt work)
- Finding *.zip file from extracted *.exe and File.Copy to removable media
- Delete folder created by 7z Process (Process is killed)
- Program close and delete himself (Its not a joke)

Structure of unzipped *.exe

- Folder

  - Folder

    - File.zip
    - Some junk as .txt or .doc

My code:

```
foreach(string[] dir in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
 if(Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(path_to_source, dir))
 {
   Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(path_to_source, dir), true);
 }
}
```

The question is: Why program close and delete himself when Directory.Delete begin.

Comment: "*Program close and delete himself*" -- sounds like antivirus?

Comment: Could worth a try, build the application and scan it with your antivirus

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I mean, an antivirus is likely deciding that your application is a virus when it tries to do the deletion, and is stopping it and quarantining / deleting it. I'm not suggesting that your application *is* a virus, just that an antivirus might be mistaking it for one

Comment: Does the code that you are running reside in the directory that you are deleting?

Comment: You are right guys. It is antivirus. We are using trendmicro at work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trendmicro antivirus is the problem.